# For integer $n > 0$, Laurent expansion of $\Gamma(-n+x) $ to $\mathcal{O}(x)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, special-functions

How to prove:

$$\Gamma(-n+x)= \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left( \frac{1}{x}+\left(-\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}  \right)  +\frac{1}{6} \left(\pi^2+3 \left(-\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}  \right)^2 +3 \left(-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^2} \right) \right)x + \mathcal{O}(x^2) \right)$$

with integer $n > 0$.

Comment: What do you get from $\Gamma(1) = 1, \Gamma'(1) = -\gamma , \Gamma(s+1) = s \Gamma(s)$ and $\Gamma(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > 0 $ ? What if you use $\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s)}$ and $\frac{\Gamma'(s)}{\Gamma(s)} = -\gamma-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{s+n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$ ?

Comment: To the OP: did you try following through with reuns's comment?

Comment: @FShrike I just saw this question's big O notation shown as a box. Then check the source code \mathcal{O}

Comment: What does that have to do with whether or not you acted on ruens’ (5 and a half years old) suggestion? I ask because it’s unclear whether you still need help with this

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/302156)